# Asp.net automate update of rss and save to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer

I have this scenario:
an Asp.net/c# website with a rss reader/parser and  a database. I would like to update the rss  every x hours and save the new records in a database.
The indications I am receiving are that I need a dedicated server and a scheduler. I am not an expert about Asp but knowing that the server has a system time, it is natural to me thinking about using a timer. 
I see that there is a timer in Asp.

Would it be possible to use a timer properly wrapped in the code, to get the functionality of the above scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you could use a timer inside a class (static or something that always has an instance activated) to accomplish this. One thing you are going to have to watch out for is that App Pools by default timeout and shutdown after 20 minutes of inactivity so you will want to change the settings to make it constantly run or make sure that something sends a request to the server every so often to keep the App Pool alive.